Phone screen stuck, flashing between normal screen and static
Google Pixel 5a: my phone suddenly went into a mode of alternating/flashing between static (random pixel noise) screen and regular display (was using the camera, no drop or physical stress). I can see the regular screen between flashes but it's too fast to allow me to unlock phone using the pattern lock. I can get into dead robot / boot recovery menu and no problem with flashing there - but I can't reset the system from there (assuming it's a corrupted OS component causing it) without erasing all my data. Any suggestions to recover from this state or just recover my data (docs/photos) will be greatly helpful 

The touch function of the display also affected? If a display behaves that way even in recovery it is a hardware problem. Possibly the cable between Mainboard and display or the hardware display driver itself has a defect which makes it interpret the display signals wrong (the random noise).

Thank you @Robert the touch function appears to be fine. For a millisecond that's in normal screen I see I'm able to complete partial pattern lock, alas, not long enough, for the entire pattern.

Pattern lock is bad as you can not use keyboard and type it blind. Therefore I strongly recommend to never use pattern lock on Android device. The pattern should always appear at the same position. Make yourself a frame (e.g. using paper) that shows the outer border of the pattern field. Align it when the screen shows the real UI and then try to draw your pattern even if the screen shows noise. Alternatively you can try small self-adhesive dots marking important pattern points (or the space between the dots), but I don't know if this affects the touch screen.
